# Crystal Reports Embeded Image Size

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-10

I am having trouble adjusting the size of an image [(EMF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile) embedded using the Crystal Reports 10 designer. I am importing the picture as an OLE object using the Insert menu and selecting picture.

I have 2 workstations which access several reports. Each workstation imports the image at a different size.

I can import and adjust the size correctly on Workstation 1 but adjusting the image's size on Workstation 2 makes the image too small.

Any advice or insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally had some oddball issues with [GDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface), and I would examine the Windows High Priority Updates and Custom Updates on both machines. You may need to apply the following [GDI+ Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18909).

The other question would be which version of Crystal Reports 10 Service Packs you have on each machine. I hope this helps some.